# URI from OnActivityResult with imageview

Tags: android

In my app, a user click a  button to open the Choser to choose a pic. On my activity result the code is

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                if(selectedImageUri!=null){
                    imageviewTest.setImageURI(selectedImageUri)

                }else{

                }

            }
        }
 }
```

The image is not displayed. I am wondering why? I noticed some people on this forum pass this value to contentresolver, why is that? Shouldn't the path be sufficient?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE) {
                BitmapFactory.Options bfOptions =new BitmapFactory.Options();
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                if(selectedImage!=null){
                    String galleryImatePath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage);
                    try{

                            bfOptions.inDither=false;          //Disable Dithering mode
                            bfOptions.inPurgeable=true;        //Tell to gc that whether it needs free memory, the Bitmap can be cleared
                            bfOptions.inInputShareable=true;   //Which kind of reference will be used to recover the Bitmap data after being clear, when it will be used in the future 
                            bfOptions.inSampleSize=5;
                            bfOptions.inTempStorage=new byte[32 * 1024];
                            InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
                            final Bitmap myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null , bfOptions);
                            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            myImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
                            bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
                            imageviewTest.setImageBitmap(myImage)

                }else{

                }

            }
        }
 }

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! that works. when displaying the pic, should I use the compress method? Or the sampling method?